# Ideas for Quick Hierarchical Listing - .NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, data-binding

I have a table in SQL Server listing corporate departments and their sections and subsections (3 levels).  I would like to create some web-based listing of this, but similar to a TreeList.

I was thinking to set up nested Ajax Accordions, but it was taking me way too long to put together.  I would even settle for a GridView with non-repeating column values.

Is there a way I can implement my idea without it taking me more than an hour or so for a newbie to complete?  Any controls in ASP.NET or Ajax I can bind to would be great.

Comment: Is it WebForms? Why not a [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx) control?

Comment: Third party frameworks already have a TreeList control, such as Infragistics and Telerik.

Comment: @Ozzy - Its a WebForm.  I am a little new to this, but I can't find it in the toolbox (using VS 2005).  I know I can probably add it as a reference, but I'm not seeing it.  That would be perfect if it's in there.

Comment: @Brian - I have no install rights on this PC nor do I have permission to purchase controls, unfortunately.

Comment: @Robert - If you write <asp:TreeView ID="Treeview1" runat="server"></asp:TreeView> in the markup, does it compile then? Btw, [here's](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/navigation/treeview.aspx) a tutorial (rather old) on the subject...

Comment: @Ozzy - The TreeView seems to come up. I tried to simply connect my Datasource to it, but obviously it's not that simple.  I will look at that tutorial now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ozzy, I was able to solve this simple issue using a TreeList.  Since my issue is simlper than the one in the tutorial he supplied, all I did was create DataTable for each level, and for each row I added the TreeNode (which was simply the string value of that entry).  Thanks!!